# Windows 10 Fails To Boot, and Beeping

Tags: windows-10, boot

After an unexpected shutdown my computer refuses to boot, giving me very unpleasant single short beeps, these are not beep codes, not from the BIOS, at least, as this happens after the Windows logo, and my motherboard has Debug LEDs and does not beep.

I tried Startup Repair, no success, I checked the repair logs; it says that "The boot sequence completed successfully", SFC returns "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.", Bootrec completes fine except for /fixboot, which results in "Access is denied.", CHKDSK finds no errors, and DISM also completes successfully, however the problem persists.

I have honestly never seen this behavior before; Windows normally doesn't just beep. I couldn't find any documentation on this, or any similar issues. It starts booting normally, it posts, Windows logo with spinning dots, black screen… then, more black screen, and finally a loud, short beep. The beep repeats once each ~15 seconds, 4 or 5 times, and then it reboots. Any ideas on what this means, and how to fix it?

Edit: I've been able to solve the problem, thankfully the last update created a restore point, and I was able to revert to that, fixing my install, however the question remains, not as much on "how to", as to "what". Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Also, do you know the manufacturer of your BIOS?

Comment: @Virtuality maybe consolidate your comments :)

Comment: @johnbchron Good point :D I didn't mean for them to come across as harsh; I'll improve them, no hard feelings :-)

Comment: Could you please tell me the brand of your computer and your BIOS manufacturer?

Comment: And do you have any evidence to suggest these aren't beep codes? Thanks.

Comment: @Virtuality The only evidence I have [that these aren't beep codes] is that it happens after Windows loading, so it is posting, and reverting to a restore point fixed the issue, all pointing to it being an OS problem, not a hardware problem. For the manufacturer, it is a MSI B350 Tomahawk running the latest available AMI BIOS(7A34v1OR). According to AMI, it would be a "DRAM refresh failure".